# Prove that a Lipschitz function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Define $f:[a.b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as Lipschitz

By definition, then, $\exists M>0, M \in \mathbb{R}:|f(x)-f(y)\leq M|x-y|$  $ $ $\forall x,y\in[a,b]$

Rearranging this, we have $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{x-y} \leq M$, positing that the slope must be finite on the interval $[a,b]$

I understand conceptually that Lipschitz functions must be continuous but I'm having trouble showing it.

Should I go about this by showing assuming the negation of Lipschitz and showing that for some $\epsilon,  \exists \delta>0: |f(x)-L|>\epsilon$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018140/proving-a-lipschitz-function-is-continuous?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first show that Lipshitz continuity implies uniform continuity, from which it follows that Lipshitz continuity implies continuity, because uniform continuity implies continuity.

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces and suppose $f:X\to Y$ is Lipshitz continuous. Then exists a $K\geq 0$ such that for all $x,y\in X$, we have $d_Y(f(x),f(y))\leq K\,d_X(x,y)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{K}$. Then if $v,u\in X$ satisfying $d_X(v,u)<\delta$, we have $$d_Y(f(v),f(u))\leq K\,d_X(v,u)<K\delta=K\frac{\varepsilon}{K}=\varepsilon$$

If $K=0$, then choose $\delta=\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to proceed by contradiction. Use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity and choose $\delta=\varepsilon/M$.

Answer (score -2):

If $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M}$. The definition of continuity says that we can suppose that $$0<|x-x_0|<\delta$$ from here: $$M|x-x_0|<\epsilon$$ but we now that $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<M|x-x_0|$$ because $f\in Lip(\mathbb{R})$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ and therefore $f$ is continuous.